# Get the previous month from today's date

Tags: lwuit

Is there a way in lwuit1.4  to get the the last month from todays date? I tried using the `add` method, but it is not there in lwuit's calendar api.

Answer (score 1):

That's unrelated to LWUIT, its the java.util.Calendar class from CLDC which is missing the add method. It does have the set method so you you can code something like that yourself. See the code for LWUIT's Calendar class where the arrows allow navigating between months.